# Custom widget does not display in layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a custom view that I created

```
class TravelContactDetailsWidget : ConstraintLayout {

    private lateinit var binding : TravelContactDetailsWidgetBinding

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        initView()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        initView()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        initView()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        val inflater =
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        binding = TravelContactDetailsWidgetBinding.inflate(inflater)
    }

}
```

The layout file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="@string/label_countries"
        android:textColor="@color/white_label_primary_color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</layout>
```

[image: travel_contact_details_widget]

However, when run the app after adding the widget to another layout it does not display

I have added to the fragment layout below and its empty

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUseCardAbroad"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvUseCardAbroad"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvUseCardAbroad"
        android:theme="@style/SBGSwitch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUseCardAbroad"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/switch1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUseCardAbroadDisclaimerText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/label_activate_card_note"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvUseCardAbroad"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUseCardAbroad"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />

    <com.myapp.mobile.android.travel.TravelDateRangePickerWidget
        android:id="@+id/travelDateRangePickerWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUseCardAbroadDisclaimerText"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <com.myapp.mobile.android.travel.TravelCountrySelectorWidget
        android:id="@+id/travelCountrySelectorWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/travelDateRangePickerWidget"/>

    <com.myapp.mobile.android.travel.TravelContactDetailsWidget
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/travelCountrySelectorWidget" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: fragment_travel]

Is there something that I might be missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something that I might be missing ?

You're inflating the binding and not actually doing anything with it so your custom view remains empty.

```
// Inflates binding and holds a reference but not doing anything with it
binding = TravelContactDetailsWidgetBinding.inflate(inflater)
```

To fix this, use the `inflate` version that takes the view to inflate *into*:

```
binding = TravelContactDetailsWidgetBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true)
```

Comment: yes, slight oversight on my end